Can't use UIPasteboard on Widget Swift on Real Device
So I make a widget that can copy account number using AppIntent, the function running smoothly when I run it on simulator but the copy function is does not working at all...
This is my code in the AppIntent to copy the account balance on the widget
import AppIntents
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

@available(iOSApplicationExtension 16, *)
struct CopyAccountNumberIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Copy Account Number"
    private let appGroupID: String = "appname.com"

    func perform() async throws -> some ReturnsValue<String> {
        let defaults: UserDefaults? = UserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupID)
        if let accountNumber: String = defaults?.string(forKey: "accountNumber"),
           let accountName: String = defaults?.string(forKey: "accountName") {
            let pasteboard: String = "\(accountNumber)\n\(accountName)"
            UIPasteboard.general.string = pasteboard
            return .result(value: pasteboard)
        } else {
            print("Button No account number found")
            return .result(value: "")
        }
    }
}

The function running smoothly on xcode simulator, I can copy then paste the account number on another app like message, notes, safari, etc...
But when running on the real device, it can't copy the account number and when I debug it, It return this error

...retrieving pasteboard named com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general failed with error: Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=10 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=}
...saving pasteboard failed with error: Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=11 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=}

your help would be greatly appreciated thank you in advance!

Possibly related - Using UIPasteboard in a keyboard extension. The important bit is that both a widget and a keyboard extension are separate processes/targets than the app itself, so they need their own Info.plist setup and entitlements.

@DávidPásztor still not working, I'm using default(built-in) keyboard, I also added in widget target info.plist
